# Unable to setup MS SQL server access via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

The setup:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- PHP version: 7.2.10
- ODBC v17 Installed

php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll and php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll (all dll's are in C:\xampp\php\ext)

Loaded Configuration File   C:\xampp\php\php.ini

php.ini:

```
line 1965 of php.ini:
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

lines 910-913: (previoius attempt)
[PHP_SQLSRV]
;extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"  
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

cmd iisreset and Apache Server restarted between each attempt

But I am getting

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

I've also completely closed xampp and restarted it a number of times.

[image: PHP Info]

To be clear, there is NO php.ini file in C:\Windows
Opening php.ini via Xampp's config button opens C:\xampp\php\php.ini and that is the file I've been modifying.

This now appears in PHP Info:
[image: SQLSRV extension showing]

```
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

[08-Apr-2021 22:20:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 15:20:07 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\ms_sql_test.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\ms_sql_test.php on line 19
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 22:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86 (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[08-Apr-2021 15:20:23 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\ms_sql_test.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\ms_sql_test.php on line 19
[08-Apr-2021 15:20:25 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\ms_sql_test.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\ms_sql_test.php on line 19

Comment: My guess, you've editted the wrong php.ini file. Is `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` really the `php.ini` file that apache is using?

Comment: One dll is thread safe (ts) and the other is not (nts,) that is probably your problem. Check if your php is ts or nts and download the correct dll ;)

Comment: Thank you I'll double check both of these right now!

Comment: re: Orry, I've tried all 4 dll's, none work.  PHP Info says thread safety is enabled so I will keep php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll as PHP info is actually reporting architecture x86

Comment: @Larnu, wouldn't it be the one PHP Info's Loaded Configuration File points to?

Comment: @Mikey Have you modified your php.ini to: `extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll` ? Have you restarted apache after pasting the new dll and changing the ini file?

Comment: @Mikey And if you haven't done already so, try to put the extension reference at the end of your ini file

Comment: @Orry, yes per the post and comments above, I added that line to the php.ini file pointed to by PHP Info.  Extension reference as in "extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext""?  Will try that now, had it in there previously.  And yes I've been restarting every try.

Comment: Update: I have attempted all of the above in every combination and permutation possible and the error persists.

Comment: If you create a file with just `<?php
phpinfo();
?>` in it, where does it say your `php.ini` file is?

Comment: Larnu it is giving me somewhat conflicting info.  I will post a screenshot above.

Comment: I've attempted everything mentioned above and added results to the original post where appropriate.  Please let me know what else I should try!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by correcting the versions of Microsoft's dll's designed to work with the version of PHP I had.

My PHP is v7.2
php_sqlsrv_7_XX_XX.dll does not work with PHP 7.2

I instead had to download php_sqlsrv.dll from https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/5.9.0preview1/windows
to match my PHP v7.2

Doing this and then updating the config instantly fixed the issue (after an Apache reboot)!

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#driver-versions to get the correct version of MS' dll to match the version of PHP you're running.